# how improve website mainpage loading

Tags: rss, feed

I'm using [feed to post RSS Aggregator] and get posts from 44 sites. main page loading is too slow. I checked GTmetrix and it seems good but I don't know how can I improve my website loading. http://akhbartop.ir/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also different **WordPress caching plugins**.

In fact, caching plugins are often very complex. It may be a trouble learning how to use them at first, but it may pay out later.

It will take a lot of nerves and lot of coffee, but eventually you will prevail.

In theory, it looks easy:

[image]

Comment: now im using wp rocket plugin and its awesome

Answer (score 1):

Loading RSS feeds over network is extremely slow operation. WP's `fetch_feed()` has built-in caching for it, but it won't help much if one page has to check feeds in number of dozens.

This is likely unsolvable without fetching feeds completely asynchronously from page load (not something WP can natively do) and without plugin you use making proper use of that.

Though *guessing* the performance bottleneck is rarely certain. You should figure out what takes time in your case specifically. There is range of tools for that from WP plugins (such as Query Monitor) to proper PHP profilers (such as Blackfire).

Comment: Hello, this is the first time I attempt to do this. Could you please guide me step by step for troubleshooting this using the Blackfire or Query monitor plugin?

Thanks again

Comment: No, Unfortunately this troubleshooting performance isn't something that can be reduced to step by step instructions. Look up the tools, start to use them, ask about specific challenges you are facing.